# javascript array clarification

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I'm new to Javascript and have this issue:

```
console.log(results1[1]);
```

prints: `[ { product_identification_category_id: 1, title: 'Title1' } ]`

```
console.log(results1[1].product_identification_category_id);
```

prints undefined.  I was expecting this to print 1.

Am I misunderstanding something?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like `results1[1]` is, itself, an array (with one entry). So you'd want

```
console.log(results1[1][0].product_identification_category_id);
// The new bit --------^^^
```

Comment: Yep, adding the new bit fixed it.  results1[1] is not meant to be an array, so I guess I have an issue somewhere else :).  Thanks!